# any source for night-time aerial images (on street level-bird eye view)?

Tags: aerial-photography

I'm currently in search of a dataset featuring nighttime aerial images. While I'm familiar with sources such as Google Earth's nighttime view, I've noticed that this dataset lacks detailed lighting information as you zoom in closer to urban areas. I'm seeking a dataset that provides the level of detail shown in the image below, covering cities in the UK or any other part of the world:

[image]

If anyone is aware of a dataset like this, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Thank you in advance!